# Google app maker Loading image

Tags: google-app-maker

In sample projects loading image is shown when a process or event is on going. How to configure loading image for a button click or page loading can anyone give a example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will update `src` attribute of the `img` DOM element and force browser to (re)load image:

```
// onClick event of some button/widget
app.currentPage.descendants.ImageWidget.url = 'http://cats.com/myCat.jpg';
```